# Is it possible to animate a plot with plotly express when the pandas dataframe is containing arrays instead of values?

Tags: python, animation, plotly

I would like to animate a plot using px.scatter using a panda dataframe which contains arrays instead of values. Unfortunately, my approach doesn't work since I cannot access the values inside the brackets in the cells of the dataframe. In this way, I would like to create a diagram which shows more data for each animation frame.
Below you find an example.
I would really appreciate your help!

````
import pandas as pd
import random
import plotly_express as px
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
i_list = []

N = 10
for i in range(N):
    d1[i] = list(range(0,i))
    d2[i] = list(random.sample(range(10, 30), i))
    i_list.append(i)

res_v1 = list(d1.values())
res_v2 = list(d2.values())

d = {'a' : res_v1, 'b' : res_v2, 'i' : i_list}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

fig = px.scatter(df, x = 'a', y = 'b', animation_frame = 'i')
fig.show()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was able to plot the below:

```
fig = px.scatter(df.iloc[9], x = df['a'][9], y = df['b'][9], animation_frame = i_list[0:9])
fig.show()
```

Comment: Hello, thank-you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, that is not what I would like to plot. Animation frame should be i_list. I would like that for each iteration the number of points on the chart increase.